# How to fix NPM run build, manifest validation problem with enum value

Tags: powerapps, pcf, power-platform

I am trying to follow along with a PCF tutorial and have run into an error when running the command 'npm run build' when trying to build my component.
This is the terminal log:

npm run build

> pcf-project@1.0.0 build
> pcf-scripts build`

`[2:55:25 pm] [build]  Initializing... [2:55:25 pm] [build]  Validating manifest... [2:55:25 pm] [build]  Failed: [pcf-1014] [Error] Manifest validation problem: instance.manifest.control[0].property[0].$.of-type is not one of enum values: Whole.None,TwoOptions,DateAndTime.DateOnly,DateAndTime.DateAndTime,Decimal,Enum,FP,Multiple,Currency,OptionSet,SingleLine.Email,hole.None,TwoOptions,DateAndTime.DateOnly,DateAndTime.DateSingleLine.Text,SingleLine.TextArea,SingleLine.URL,SingleLine.Ticker,SingleLine.Phone,Object,File,Lookup.Simple,Lookup.Customerine.Ticker,SingleLine.Phone,Object,File,Lookup.Simple,LookAndTime,Decimal,Enum,FP,Multiple,Currency,OptionSet,Lookup.Owner,Lookup.PartyList,Lookup.Regarding,MultiSelectOptionSet                                                                                                                     garding,MultiSelectOptionSet`
`
Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am still new to coding so not really sure where to start

Comment: Provide your manifest file, please.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, you need to check the manifest schema reference and make sure that the of-type attribute of your property element matches one of the enum values listed there. For example, if your property is a single line of text, you can use **SingleLine.Text** as the of-type value. If your property is a lookup field, you can use **Lookup.Simple** or one of the other lookup subtypes as the of-type value.